# WPF: Binding Combobox in Code Behind to Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

This might be something very straight forward and I really think it should work as is, but it doesn't... I have the following scenario:

```
var itemSource = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("ItemList"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneTime
};       

comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, itemSource);
```

ItemList is simply:

```
public IList<string> ItemList
{
   get
   {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionsEnum)).ToList();
   }
}
```

I would have expected this to bind the list of items to the Combobox, and when I do it in XAML it works fine, but I have to do it in code behind...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in code?

Comment: Has to be done in code as I bind the combo box to a different property depending on a certain setting. Could put two separate combo boxes in the UI and bind them in XAML, then set visibility on the one i need, but think that's just not the right way to go if I can do the code behind route.

Comment: I'd create a property in the view model that checked the setting and exposed the appropriate list rather than screwing around with code-behind.  It's much easier to test.

Comment: Great point Robert... hadn't thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the following comment as my answer:

> I'd create a property in the view
>   model that checked the setting and
>   exposed the appropriate list rather
>   than screwing around with code-behind.
>   It's much easier to test. – Robert
>   Rossney

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Combobox's `DataContext` to the `ItemList`'s parent object?
So `comboBox.DataContext = MyObj;` where MyObj has the ItemList property on it.

Comment: Yup, set it to that already, sorry, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Check again thet the *DataContext* is set to the object that have the *ItemList* property.
A very good way see what is the real DataContext is to use [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/).
There is no problem with your code, Jast the *DataContext*.